# vue, как рендерить несколько элементов?

Tags: vue.js

есть такой template:

```
<template>  
    <header class='header'>
        {{ msgHead }}
    </header>
    <input class='input-add' type='text' v-model='textTodo' @keypress.enter='addTodo' />
    <ul class='todos' v-if='todos.length'>
        <Todo
            v-for='todo in todos'
            :key='todo.name'
            :todo='todo'
            @remove='removeTodo'
        />
    </ul>
</template>
```

Какие есть способы это отрендерить? Оборачивать в дополнительный тег ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, необходимо обернуть всё, что внутри `template` в `div`.

Vue необходимо, чтобы корневой элемент был только один, поэтому:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <header class='header'>
            {{ msgHead }}
        </header>
        <input 
            class='input-add' 
            type='text' v-model='textTodo' 
            @keypress.enter='addTodo' 
        />
        <ul class='todos' v-if='todos.length !== 0'>
            <Todo
                v-for='todo in todos'
                :key='todo.name'
                :todo='todo'
                @remove='removeTodo'
            />
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```